# Windows service installed successfully but not responding after started

Tags: c#, windows-services, timer

I have a windows service written in C#, .Net framework 2.0. I installed it on three machines and it worked fine but on one machine (with .Net framework 2.0) the setup has installed the service successfully but the service is not responding after I start it. I check for this by checking whether a log file is created at a specific path insribed in the config file or not. This log file is created everytime the timer elapses the interval time. I'm unable to figure out the reason. Have checked all the parameters but unable to get any solution to this.

The funny thing is that the same setup is running well on other machines.

P.S.: I have admin access on all the servers I'm installing this service on.

Comment: Are there ANY differences between the 3 machines? Any at all?

Comment: yes. The one m not able to get the result on is on MS Windows server 2003, Enterprise Edition. 
Two machines on which successful they are on MS Windows XP. Another machine on which successful is on MS Windows server 2003 again. Now, this 2003 machine is a development machine and the other on which m unable to get successful result is production. So, maybe there are some checks or rights or something else stopping the service to access the EXE. That is what I'm trying to figure out.
Is it possible to have the code of the service give an issue even if m using it with .Net framework 2.0 itself?

Answer (score 0):

Can you get VS on the machine? Even the express edition would probably be fine. In the service's Initialization function you can call debugger.launch. This should get you in.

Comment: difficult to get VS on that machine.... that is the issue... Will give it a shot though.. but anything else that u can think of?

Comment: You can also do remote debugging and attach to the process, but thats always a bit of a pain in a corporate environment. At least depending on how tough your systems people are.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is almost always a permissions issue with the user account the service is running under.  Quick way to check this is to make the service account a local machine admin and see if it works.  If it does, you need to figure out what permissions the service account you are supposed to use is missing.

Comment: I am running it under local machine admin itself but still not working... and difficult to get VS on that machine.... that is the issue... Will give it a shot though.. but anything else that u can think of?